# On click of parent node in tree layout, Like link and node, linkText should also exit

Tags: d3.js, svg, tree, data-visualization

On click of parent node in tree layout, link and linktext should exit. Link is exiting but not the linktext. Here is the jsfiddle [project](https://jsfiddle.net/44nd20gk/).                  I tried the code - `svg.selectAll(".line-label").remove();` which was deleting the linkText from all the labels that should not happen. What i am expecting is on click of node it exits the linkText like link and node from the current branch of the tree not from the whole tree itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by 
Adding link like this in update:

```
//add text to the link
svg.selectAll(".line-label").data(links).enter().append("text")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "Black")
    .attr("class", "line-label")
    .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + (d.target.y - 30) + "," + (d.target.x - 10) + ")";
        })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {

    return d.target.label;
});
//remove the link text in update
svg.selectAll(".line-label").data(links).exit().remove();
```

Full running code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/6ne1qpmn/3/)

Hope this clarifies your concern! :)

Comment: Cyril, linkText is getting removed from whole tree. If i will again click on the  child node for further expansion for tree then on that particular branch link exit event, it should delete the linkText from that branch only. But it is removing from whole tree. For tree depth more than one it is not working.